# What happens after modifying Kafka topic replication factor?

Tags: apache-kafka

According to the [docs](https://kafka.apache.org/081/ops.html), you just modify a topic to increase the replication factor.

```
 > bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper zk_host:port/chroot --create --topic my_topic_name 
       --partitions 20 --replication-factor 3 --config x=y
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't specify what happens then after you modify the topic. Do existing log segments get replicated to the new replicas, or only new messages?

Comment: This link is really helpful in answering your question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46289511/kafka-reassignment-of-consumer-offsets-incorrect

Answer (score 0):

For kafka 10 you need to invoke the kafka-reassign-partitions.sh script to change the replication factor of the topic.
Here is a demo of a script that will display the topic before and after the change:

```
updateTopicReplication() {
    TOPIC_NAME=$1
    REPLICAS=$2

    echo "****************************************"
    echo "describe $TOPIC_NAME"
    bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --describe --topic $TOPIC_NAME

    JSON_FILE=./configChanges/${TOPIC_NAME}-update.json
    echo $JSON_FILE
    [ -e $JSON_FILE ] && rm $JSON_FILE

    touch $JSON_FILE

    echo -e "{\"version\":1, \"partitions\":[{\"topic\":\"${TOPIC_NAME}\",\"partition\":0,\"replicas\":[${REPLICAS}]}]}" >> $JSON_FILE

    echo "****************************************"
    echo "updateing $TOPIC_NAME"
    bin/kafka-reassign-partitions.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --reassignment-json-file $JSON_FILE --execute

    echo "****************************************"
    echo "describe $TOPIC_NAME"
    bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --describe --topic $TOPIC_NAME
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of *what happens* when you change the replication factor

Answer (score -2):

It seems that kafka actually doesn't support increasing (or decreasing) the replication factor for a topic, according to the same docs I mentioned in the question.

Comment: the reassign-partitions script allows you to increase the replication factor, http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#basic_ops_increase_replication_factor. decreasing is not that straightforward, but what is documented here worked for me, https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-2267

Comment: According to https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Replication+tools#Replicationtools-4.ReassignPartitionsTool this is not the correct way to do it. The JSON file generated above will output sth like:

`{"version":1, "partitions":[{"topic":"mytopic","partition":0,"replicas":[3]}]}`

whereas the desired setting here would be `"replicas":[1,2,3]`