# Kafka reassignment of __consumer_offsets incorrect?

Tags: apache-kafka, replication

I am confused with how kafka-reassignment-paritions works for __consumer_offsets topic?

I start with 1 zk and 1 kafka broker, create a test topic with replication=1, partition=1. consume and produce. works fine.

I see __consumer_offsets topic created.

Now I add a second broker with, **offsets.topic.replication.factor=2**.
I run the,

**kafka-reassign-partitions --zookeeper zookeeper1:2181 --topics-to-move-json-file topics-to-move.json --broker-list "101,102" --generate**

The generated reassignment does not look right. Only shows one replica even though there are 2 live brokers.

I was hoping to get following replicas for each partition: 
[101, 102] or [201, 101]

```
{
  "version": 1,
  "partitions": [
    {
      "topic": "__consumer_offsets",
      "partition": 19,
      "replicas": [101]
    },
    {
      "topic": "__consumer_offsets",
      "partition": 30,
      "replicas": [102]
    },
    {
      "topic": "__consumer_offsets",
      "partition": 47,
      "replicas": [101]
    }, ...
```

Appreciate any suggestion.

-Vms

Comment: Your reassignment json file isn't correct. You need to change the replica field to hold current replica location and new locations. Use --generate option in reassignment command to generate valid json

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to increase the replication factor for a topic, follow steps below:

1. Create a json file containing the reassignment plan. In your case, the file might look like:

   ```
   {"version":1, "partitions":[
     {"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":0,"replicas":[101,102]}, 
     {"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":1,"replicas":[102,101]},
     {"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":2,"replicas":[101,102]},
     {"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":3,"replicas":[102,101]},
     ...
     {"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":49,"replicas":[101,102]}
   ]}
   ```
2. Run command below to increase RF for this internal topic:

   ```
   bin/kafka-reassign-partitions.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --reassignment-json-file reassign.json --execute
   ```

Then run `kafka-topics.sh --describe` to see if replication factor is bumped up to 2.

Comment: Thanks @amethystic. This worked. I needed to run this in code, as new brokers are added, instead of the script. Used the following,         ReassignPartitionsCommand.executeAssignment(zkUtils, reassignPartitionJson, new Throttle(-1, null));

Answer (score 1):

You can use the reassignment tool to generate json for your own advantage. In your topics-to-move.json, instead of putting partition values, put `{"version":1, "topics":[{"topic":"__consumer_offsets"}]}`

Now when you run `kafka-reassign-partitions --zookeeper zookeeper1:2181 --topics-to-move-json-file topics-to-move.json --broker-list "101,102" --generate` You will get recommended partition assignment from tool.

Save that file as reassignment-proposed.json and store old assignment into rollback.json.

Use that file to start reassignment `/kafka-reassign-partitions.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --reassignment-json-file reassignment-proposed.json --execute`
Verify assignment using `--verify` option

Comment: this has massively helped me! than you sir