# Getting the below message in connect.log of the Apache Kafka : Why I am loosing records in target

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am getting below message in the Apache Kafka connect.log.

`WARN [Producer clientId=producer-2] Received invalid metadata error in produce request on partition connect-status-4 due to org.apache.kafka.com mon.errors.NotLeaderOrFollowerException: For requests intended only for the leader, this error indicates that the broker is not the current leader. For requests intended for any replica, this error indicates that the broker is not a replica of the topic partition.. Going to request metadata update now ( org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender:628)`

`ERROR [ReplicaManager broker=0] Error processing append operation on partition __consumer_offsets-13 (kafka.server.ReplicaManager) org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NotEnoughReplicasException: The size of the current ISR Set(0) is insufficient to satisfy the min.isr requirement of 2 for partition __consumer_offsets-13`

Can anyone help with the details? Does this indicate all things are properly configured. Do I need to tweak anymore in Kafka?

I am loosing some records, even though with all required precautions

I have a 3 server/broker cluster

```
[UAT-Kafka,Zookeeper user@ip-XX-XX-XX-XX1 logs]$ /opt/Kafka/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --zookeeper XX.XX.XX.XX1:2181
Topic: __consumer_offsets       PartitionCount: 50      ReplicationFactor: 1    Configs: compression.type=producer,cleanup.policy=compact,segment.bytes=104857600
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 0    Leader: 2       Replicas: 2     Isr: 2
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 1    Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 2    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 3    Leader: 2       Replicas: 2     Isr: 2
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 4    Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 5    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 6    Leader: 2       Replicas: 2     Isr: 2
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 7    Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 8    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 9    Leader: 2       Replicas: 2     Isr: 2
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 10   Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 11   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 12   Leader: 2       Replicas: 2     Isr: 2
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 13   Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 14   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 15   Leader: 2       Replicas: 2     Isr: 2
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 16   Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 17   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 18   Leader: 2       Replicas: 2     Isr: 2
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 19   Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 20   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 21   Leader: 2       Replicas: 2     Isr: 2
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 22   Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 23   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 24   Leader: 2       Replicas: 2     Isr: 2
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 25   Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 26   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 27   Leader: 2       Replicas: 2     Isr: 2
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 28   Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 29   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 30   Leader: 2       Replicas: 2     Isr: 2
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 31   Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 32   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 33   Leader: 2       Replicas: 2     Isr: 2
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 34   Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 35   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 36   Leader: 2       Replicas: 2     Isr: 2
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 37   Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 38   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 39   Leader: 2       Replicas: 2     Isr: 2
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 40   Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 41   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 42   Leader: 2       Replicas: 2     Isr: 2
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 43   Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 44   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 45   Leader: 2       Replicas: 2     Isr: 2
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 46   Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 47   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 48   Leader: 2       Replicas: 2     Isr: 2
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 49   Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
Topic: connect-configs  PartitionCount: 1       ReplicationFactor: 1    Configs: cleanup.policy=compact
        Topic: connect-configs  Partition: 0    Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
Topic: connect-offsets  PartitionCount: 25      ReplicationFactor: 1    Configs: cleanup.policy=compact
        Topic: connect-offsets  Partition: 0    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: connect-offsets  Partition: 1    Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
        Topic: connect-offsets  Partition: 2    Leader: 2       Replicas: 2     Isr: 2
        Topic: connect-offsets  Partition: 3    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: connect-offsets  Partition: 4    Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
        Topic: connect-offsets  Partition: 5    Leader: 2       Replicas: 2     Isr: 2
        Topic: connect-offsets  Partition: 6    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: connect-offsets  Partition: 7    Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
        Topic: connect-offsets  Partition: 8    Leader: 2       Replicas: 2     Isr: 2
        Topic: connect-offsets  Partition: 9    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: connect-offsets  Partition: 10   Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
        Topic: connect-offsets  Partition: 11   Leader: 2       Replicas: 2     Isr: 2
        Topic: connect-offsets  Partition: 12   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: connect-offsets  Partition: 13   Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
        Topic: connect-offsets  Partition: 14   Leader: 2       Replicas: 2     Isr: 2
        Topic: connect-offsets  Partition: 15   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: connect-offsets  Partition: 16   Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
        Topic: connect-offsets  Partition: 17   Leader: 2       Replicas: 2     Isr: 2
        Topic: connect-offsets  Partition: 18   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: connect-offsets  Partition: 19   Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
        Topic: connect-offsets  Partition: 20   Leader: 2       Replicas: 2     Isr: 2
        Topic: connect-offsets  Partition: 21   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: connect-offsets  Partition: 22   Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
        Topic: connect-offsets  Partition: 23   Leader: 2       Replicas: 2     Isr: 2
        Topic: connect-offsets  Partition: 24   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
Topic: connect-status   PartitionCount: 5       ReplicationFactor: 1    Configs: cleanup.policy=compact
        Topic: connect-status   Partition: 0    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: connect-status   Partition: 1    Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
        Topic: connect-status   Partition: 2    Leader: 2       Replicas: 2     Isr: 2
        Topic: connect-status   Partition: 3    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: connect-status   Partition: 4    Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
Topic: uat.VehicleMessage.topic   PartitionCount: 1       ReplicationFactor: 1    Configs:
        Topic: uat.VehicleMessage.topic   Partition: 0    Leader: 2       Replicas: 2     Isr: 2
Topic: uat.error.topic  PartitionCount: 1       ReplicationFactor: 1    Configs:
        Topic: uat.error.topic  Partition: 0    Leader: 2       Replicas: 2     Isr: 2
Topic: uat.vehicle.topic        PartitionCount: 6       ReplicationFactor: 1    Configs:
        Topic: uat.vehicle.topic        Partition: 0    Leader: 2       Replicas: 2     Isr: 2
        Topic: uat.vehicle.topic        Partition: 1    Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
        Topic: uat.vehicle.topic        Partition: 2    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: uat.vehicle.topic        Partition: 3    Leader: 2       Replicas: 2     Isr: 2
        Topic: uat.vehicle.topic        Partition: 4    Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
        Topic: uat.vehicle.topic        Partition: 5    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
Topic: uat.productinfo.topic    PartitionCount: 3       ReplicationFactor: 1    Configs:
        Topic: uat.vehicleinfo.topic    Partition: 0    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: uat.vehicleinfo.topic    Partition: 1    Leader: 2       Replicas: 2     Isr: 2
        Topic: uat.vehicleinfo.topic    Partition: 2    Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
Topic: uat.testMetrics.topic    PartitionCount: 1       ReplicationFactor: 1    Configs:
        Topic: uat.testMetrics.topic    Partition: 0    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
```

I am monitoring system round the clock, it should not be failing with any records, but the target sometimes has overdose/extra records else no records for some tables.[image: All Parameter Files]

Comment: _target sometimes has overdose/extra records_ - As I answered before, Kafka consumers aren't guaranteed to be exactly once... _else no records for some tables_ - Again, you're still not showing us the `/status` API response. And also have some replication factors that are not 3, which could result in data loss if you restart any broker

Comment: Which status you are looking for? Please give the command. How the replication factors can be made 3, parameters are already given with replication factor 3. How to guarantee consumers to be exactly once minimum and without no loss of records.

Comment: The Connect REST API. E.g. `curl http://localhost:8083/file-stream-distributed/status`... And your image for connect-distributed  show three lines for `replication.factor=1`. Your code blocks show there is only one replica and ISR, despite what your `server.properties` has. For example, you want lines with `Isr: 2,1,0`... Changing the property file after the topic is created won't modify the topic. I already told you, as a client, that you cannot guarantee consumer processing duplicates or drops. Only Snowflake can answer how their code works and handles certain edge cases.

Comment: True..How to make the ISR:2,1,0 and what should be the entries in server.properties and connect-distributed.properties for the replication to happen properly

Comment: [UAT-Kafka,Zookeeper deploy@ip-XX-XX-XX-XX1 config]$ curl XX.XX.XX.XX1:8083/connectors/file-stream-distributed/status
{"name":"file-stream-distributed","connector":{"state":"RUNNING","worker_id":"XX.XX.XX.XX2:8083"},"tasks":[{"id":0,"state":"RUNNING","worker_id":"XX.XX.XX.XX2:8083"}],"type":"unknown"}[UAT-Kafka,Zookeeper deploy@ip-XX-XX-XX-XX1 config]$

Comment: Over here the command curl is giving the output with the running status for the server 2 on the server 1. But as there are 3 servers in the cluster

Comment: 2022-07-04 18:27:08,879] INFO [GroupCoordinator 0]: Assignment received from leader for group connect-cluster for generation 2976 (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2022-07-04 18:27:08,879] ERROR [ReplicaManager broker=0] Error processing append operation on partition __consumer_offsets-13 (kafka.server.ReplicaManager)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NotEnoughReplicasException: The size of the current ISR Set(0) is insufficient to satisfy the min.isr requirement of 2 for partition __consumer_offsets-13 ***getting this error***

Comment: 1) You have `tasks.max=1`, so you'll only see one task's status. 2) Like I said, nothing you've shown has more than one replica, so you're getting `NotEnoughReplicasException`. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46289511/kafka-reassignment-of-consumer-offsets-incorrect

Comment: But if you add tasks.max=2 or 3 the number of duplicates are more..

Comment: That's not a Connect API problem. That's a Snowflake connector problem, which I've never used, so can't tell you how to fix that